# Delete a property from an object without creating a new one (No delete operateur)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

With Lodash `omit` for example to remove properties of an object with this piece of code :

```
this.current.obj = omit(this.current.obj, ['sellerSupportWeb', 'sellerSupportAgency', 'sellerSupportAgent'])
```

But this will create another object `this.current.obj`, but in my case I need to keep the same object

You have an alternative solution ? But not the `delete` operator

Comment: What do you mean "need to keep the same object"? You need to objects - old one (with the properties) and new one (without them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.unset()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#unset) to remove a property from an object:

```js
var obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

_.unset(obj, 'a');

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

> You have an alternative solution ? But not the `delete` operator

Nope. Your choices are create a new object with only the properties you want, or use the `delete` operator to remove the property from the existing object (which may have a significant impact on property lookup performance, although whether that actually matters will depend on how often you're using that object's properties).

Okay, technically you could wrap a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object around the original and use the `has`, `ownKeys`, `get`, etc. hooks to pretend the property doesn't exist. But you'd have to be accessing it through the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no alternative solution. I would strongly advise to use pure functional approach: don't modify variables, but transform them and create new ones. If you need to keep the same object (the same memory allocation) then `delete` operator is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property to undefined, then when you try to access to it the result will be the same that if the property had not exists.

```
myObject = {
    myProp = 'myValue'
}

myObject.myProp = undefined;
console.log(myObject.myProp);
console.log(myObject.inexistentProp);
```